Unable to log errors in error_log.log file in databricks community edition
I'm new to PySpark and Databricks, and I'm trying to log any errors to an error_log.log file located at dbfs:/FileStore/logs/error_log.log.
I created an empty log file initially and then ran the following code to simulate an error and log it:
import logging

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR, filename='/dbfs/FileStore/logs/error_log1.log')

class DataLoader:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

    def load_json(self):
        try:
            json_df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json(self.path)
            return json_df
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Error loading JSON file from {self.path}: {e}")
            return None

# Calling DataLoader
json1 = DataLoader("dbfs:/FileStore/tables/sample_dataaaaaa.json") 
json_df = json1.load_json()

# Check if the DataFrame is not None before displaying
if json_df is not None:
    json_df.display()
else:
    print("DataFrame could not be loaded. Check the logs for details.")

However, when an error occurs (e.g., a file not found), nothing is written to the log file at dbfs:/FileStore/logs/error_log1.log. The code executes, but the log file remains empty.
when i use a temp file the code and then i copy the temp file to the permanent file.
import logging

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR, filename='/tmp/error_log.log') #tempfile used

class DataLoader:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path=path

    def load_json(self):
        try:
            json_df=spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json(self.path)
            return json_df
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Error loading JSON file from {self.path}: {e}")
            return None


# Copy the log file from /tmp/ to DBFS
dbutils.fs.cp("file:/tmp/error_log.log", "dbfs:/FileStore/error_log.log")

What could be causing the logs not to be written to the specified file, and how can I ensure that error messages are logged correctly?
I'm using the community edition of Databricks,Any help would be greatly appreciated!
